# github actions maven step failing but shown as success

Tags: github-actions, maven-surefire-plugin

i am trying to run curcumber test with maven on github actions.

If i run the test(which should fail) the test is failing but shown as success.
Do you have an hit what is missing?

Maven test is failing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfB0k.png)

But Job i shown as success:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT9dI.png)

code from my actions file

```
- name: Set up JDK  
      uses: actions/setup-java@v4.0.0
      with:
        distribution: adopt
        java-version: '8'
        
    - name: Run tests with maven
      run: mvn -Dchromedriver_exe_path=${{ env.chromedriver_exe_path }} -Dbrowser=${{ env.browser }} -Denvironment=${{ env.environment }} -Dset_browser_dimensions=${{ env.use_monitor_size }} -Dheadless=true "-Dcucumber.filter.tags=${{ env.tags }}" -D clean verify --no-transfer-progress
      env:
        DISPLAY: ":2"

 
    - name: Process maven surefire reports
      uses: scacap/action-surefire-report@v1
      with:
       report_paths: '**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
```

Job should be shown as failed

Comment: You might have a setting like `<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>` your pom.xml, which prevents mvn command from exiting with status code >0

Comment: Many thanks a lot you saved my day! this was the issue (it was set to true)